# Custom OSD Keyboard suggestion

Tags: wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I tryed this [example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31908/Creating-On-Screen-Keyboard-Using-Attached-Behavio) with two type of fields with style MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox and MaterialDesignFloatingHintPasswordBox, but I noticed that when the event get is triggered the popup is showed correctly but when I go to the popup to press one of the button, the lost focus event of the text field is triggered and the popup is closed :/

My question is that do you know some solutions? Or do you know some osd keyboard that works with the materialdesignxamltoolkit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem:
is not a problem of user controls or xamltoolkit, but only a focus problem, so setting property **Focusable = false** in the button and other controls in the old keyboard works very well.

I hope that this post can be useful to someone that have my same problem.

Cheers

Franco